# Workflow is not triggering when the sharepoint list item is updated programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, development

I am using the following code to update the list item and trigger the workflow. But the workflow is not triggering when the item is updated.
Any thoughts on this.

```
 using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://spweb02:91/test"))
                {
                    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                    {


                        SPUserToken tokentemp = web.SiteUsers[@"i:0#.w|testdomain\" + "gs-test-r"].UserToken;


                        using (SPSite sitetemp = new SPSite("http://spweb02:91/test", tokentemp))
                        {
                            using (SPWeb webtemp = sitetemp.OpenWeb())
                            {

                                try
                                {
                                    sitetemp.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                                    webtemp.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true; 
                                    SPList parentlist = webtemp.Lists["Test"];
                                    SPListItem parent = parentlist.Items[0];
                                    parent["Title"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();                           

                                    parent.Update();
                                    webtemp.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                                    sitetemp.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;

                                }
                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {


                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Updates to items made by the system account will never fire a workflow. Is this the case here?

Comment: It is not system account, I am using the normal user account as mentioned in the code but still the workflow is not triggering.

Comment: Ok that wasn't clear to me if it was a system account. I afraid I won't be of much help then. The only thing I can add is if you choose to use Jquery I have a working example that's triggering the workfloow on the newly created item.

Comment: Actually the workflow has to be triggered when the item is updated pro-grammatically. Users are not updating the items from UI.

Comment: Then you have to make sure that whatever user as triggering the workflow isn't considered a system account. It doesn't matter if a user is updating an item from the UI or for Access for instance (Since it runs under the user credentials)

Comment: Do  you have check-in/out functionality enabled on the list? in the past I had issue with that I had to check out, update, check in and only then the wf would trigger.

Comment: The user which is triggering the workflow is not system account and checkin and checkouts are not enabled in that list.

Comment: Please don't forget to accept the helpful reply as the best answer. Or, share your own solution and accept it as the best answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the following code after `SPListItem.Update()`.

```
SPSite.WorkflowManager.Dispose();
```

For example:

```
using(SPSite site = new SPSite(url))
{
    using(SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPList list = web.GetList(url);
        SPListItem item = list.Items[1];
        item[updateField] = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
        item.Update();
        site.WorkflowManager.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Refer to:

[SPListItem.Update() not starting workflow](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/malag/2008/07/11/splistitem-update-not-starting-workflow/)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.. The above mentioned solution is working fine now.. Thanks a lot..